# How to fix 'ActionController::ParameterMissing" error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a quiz app, and want the form to send the user's answer to the controller, but can't get past this error.

Most answers I've read appear to point to .permit and .require methods as the culprits, so I've tried every permutation of them I can.

The form from my view:

```rb
<%= form_tag("/cardstates/#{@nextcard.id}/update", method: "post") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag("answer[first]") %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit Answer") %>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```rb
class CardstatesController < ApplicationController

    def update
        @nextcard = Cardstate.find(params[:id]) 
        @user = @nextcard.user
        if @nextcard.update(cardstate_params)
            redirect_to study_path(@user)
        end
    end

    private

    def cardstate_params
        params.require(:answer).permit(:first)
    end

end
```

Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xNTQj4C4NkR0KhghqKwia/Kb0K7MI/eOWfQMfpUFXNkpK7QP560SqAKAtOqaqk4kIWAOKAKSewewL1ptGvPS+A==", "answer"=>{"first"=>"222"}, "commit"=>"Submit Answer", "id"=>"68"}
```

Relevant line from routes.rb

```rb
post 'cardstates/:id/update', to: 'cardstates#update'
```

I'd like to be able to call the answer.first (above it is 222) so I can then perform the necessary logic based on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first convert

```
post 'cardstates/:id/update', to: 'cardstates#update'
```

to

```
put 'cardstates/:id/update', to: 'cardstates#update'
```

another

```
<%= form_tag("/cardstates/#{@nextcard.id}/update", method: "post") do %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag("/cardstates/#{@nextcard.id}/update", method: "put") do %>
```

and in the controller you can simply call `cardstate_params[:answer]` and you will get 222

Comment: That did it! ***Thanks***